# Outputting a display using a clock enable

Tags: vhdl, fpga, vivado

I'm trying to output a changing value to two 7 segment displays. It's supposed to read a combination input from the switches on my board. I.e. when i_SW = "1000" then SW12 has been turned on. Under that statement I need to assign an output to D4 and D3 (My first two 7 segment displays), this is easy enough. However, I then need to output a 4 bit value that changes at every rising edge from a 2Hz clock enable. For example, 2Hz CE rising edge -> output to D2 and D1 a value of 0 0 respectively -> next rising edge -> output to D2 and D1 a value of 0 1 respectively -> return to first output after next CE rising edge.
Basically it needs to loop. The code below is what I have so far, it looks wrong in the 'counter' section but I don't know what to change it to. Could someone help me please?

```
if (i_SW = "1000") then
        i_D4 <= 0 ;
        i_D3 <= 1 ;
        if i_Reset = '1' then
            o_SC <= "0000";
        elsif (rising_edge(i_Clk)) then
            if i_CE1Hz = '1' then
                if counter = "1111" then
                   counter <= "0000";
                else
                   counter <= (counter + 1);
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
        o_SC <= counter;
```

Comment: Is there a way to 'wait for' a rising edge and then continually loop it?

Comment: Are you asking if you can create a latch on the first rising clock edge than loop the code inside of that? Sorry, it's difficult to understand what you are trying to do. You should provide all the code and the testbench associated with the code.

Comment: @Laburtz yes I think so. I don't have a testbench yet, i don't bother until I am relatively certain the code will work. There is so much code and there all separated into different entities that don't have anything to do with this entity. However, I am happy to provide the Top Level Entity if it would help?